# How do you implement a custom submit handler in hook_form_alter()?

Tags: forms, 8

I've been updating one of my Drupal 7 modules to 8 and I'm having an issue with my form alter. I'm adding a validation function and a submit handler. The validation function is getting called just fine, but the submit function is not getting fired. I'm wondering if this means there is a Symfony-style approach that needs to be taken to adding submit handlers to existing forms. I've done a lot of searching and I can't find any examples. Also looked through some work-in-progress D8 modules but I haven't really found any working examples there either.

Does anyone have any idea what the correct Drupal 8 way to do this is?

Comment: You should post your existing code so people can take a look at it and spot any issues/suggest alternatives.

Comment: There are, as of D8 beta9, getters and setters for submit handlers, but I couldn't seem to get them to work and used the answer below. I would hope the node interface gets some events dispatched in the future, as I would rather subscribe to an event than use a hook.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the example in [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) it's the same as for Drupal 7:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_upload_enabled_types_submit';
```

You can find similar (working) logic in

- [`contact_form_user_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!contact!contact.module/function/contact_form_user_form_alter/8())
- [`editor_form_filter_format_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!editor!editor.module/function/editor_form_filter_format_form_alter/8)
- [`locale_form_language_admin_edit_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!locale!locale.module/function/locale_form_language_admin_edit_form_alter/8)

And a few others besides.

Comment: I can't argue with the API docs. Probably something screwy with my implementation, I'll dig deeper.

Comment: See my update above, aside from $form['actions']['submit'] there are also $form['actions']['publish'] and ['unpublish'] sections that can have submit handlers attached.

Comment: I had to use $form['actions']['publish']['#submit'][] instead of $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] for my submit handler to work when the node was published. However, I can't seem to get the callback to work when the node is first saved as unpublished.

Answer (score 6):

You can add how many submit handler you want using the following code:

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_what_ever_function';
```

If you want to add a submit handler **after** the default submit handler, (a submit handler that will be called after the submit callback), you can use the following.

```
$form['#submit'][1] = test_function;
```

To remove the submit handler:

```
unset($form["actions"]['submit']);
```

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is either changed or differs from case to case. With the Node Delete Multiple confirmation form

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_upload_enabled_types_submit';
```

@Clive's code causes Drupal to ignore the main handler. In this case add the handler to the `$form['#submit']` section:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_upload_enabled_types_submit';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to attach a custom submit handler to the article node add/edit form in Drupal 8:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Use this to reveal the form id.
  //drupal_set_message($form_id);

  // Use this with the devel module to inspect the button action(s).
  //kint($form['actions']);

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'node_article_form':      // New article nodes.
    case 'node_article_edit_form': // Existing article nodes.

      // Attach our custom submit handler.
      $form['actions']['publish']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_node_article_form_submit';
      break;

  }

}

function my_module_node_article_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Running custom submit handler...');
}
```

I was not able to successfully append a custom submit handler to `$form['#submit']` and have the function fire properly. I *had* to explicitly attach it to the **Save and publish** button when creating a new article, and attach it to the **Save and keep published** button when editing an existing article.

Besides `publish`, here are some of the other button actions available:

```
unpublish
preview
delete
```

Comment: I'm in Drupal 8.7.3, and `my_module_node_article_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state` gave me `TypeError: Argument 2 passed to _ccad_content_log_webform_submit() must be an instance of FormStateInterface, instance of Drupal\Core\Form\FormState given`; changing it to `_submit($form, $form_state)` fixed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

To replace/override the existing handler in Drupal 9 this worked for me:

```
**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function MODULE_NAME_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit';
}

function custom_submit($form, $form_state) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus(t('Submit overriden by custom_submit!'));
}
```