# How to preserve kint output upon form submit redirection?

Tags: 8

I've [attached a custom submit handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/96529/10645) to node add/edit form for the article content type:

```
$form['actions']['publish']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_node_edit_submit';
```

In the handler, I am trying to inspect the form state values with **kint** (via the [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module):

```
kint($form_state->getValues());
```

Upon submission of the form, I'm able to briefly see the **kint** output on the screen, but I am also presented with this message:

> Redirecting to http://localhost/example.com/node/123

The page then redirects back to view the node, and the kint output is gone. How can I preserve the kint output so it is available after the redirection?

Comment: may be you could disable the direction for a while

Comment: Just to be clear, is it your own code that performs the redirection or is that something core/contrib is doing?

Comment: I think this is a devel setting that is enabled. Otherwise you would not see such message. Also xdebug a great tool to use for this.

Comment: @Clive, the redirection is done by core/kint (my submission handler does nothing but a kint output). If the kint command is removed, the redirection page is not shown. @Ivan Jaros, I looked at `admin/config/development/devel` but did not see any such settings, I shall go with xDebug.

Answer (score 10):

Use *ksm()* instead of *kint()*.

I ran into the same issue when I want to inspect the entity after saving, using drupal's [hook_entity_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) and **kint**

I found this article on [how to print variables using kint()](https://www.webwash.net/drupal/how-print-variables-using-kint-drupal-8) which explains that *ksm()* prints the output inside the drupal page (not before as kint()) does.

So this example prints the entity without redirecting:

```
function mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  ksm($entity->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behavior of the submit function, to process the form and redirect. If you want to debug this without any tools, then do a `var_dump()` and then stop the php with `die`. But debugging without tools is of course not very productive. When you want to do serious work, use xdebug and an IDE of your choice.

**Edit:**
Another way would be to use the message area, for example with drupal_set_message or dpm() from devel. This puts the debugging information in a session and you can see it after the redirect.